# Accidentally I installed efi partition to second HDD

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I have SSD and HDD. I've Windows OS installed in HDD. After when I bought SSD, I installed Windows OS to my SSD too. But didn't remove old Windows OS from HDD. Later I installed Ubuntu 20.04 to my SSD as second OS, but /boot/efi mounted to HDD efi partition even I've created additional EFI partition in SSD too. Now I'm going to remove all things from my HDD. But I don't know how to change /boot/efi partition to EFI partition from SSD.

BTW I've created in my SSD additional one more efi partition for Ubuntu in my SSD, does I need it or I can override to my Windows EFI partiton?

`/dev/sda` my HDD and `/dev/sdb` my SSD

```
/dev/sda1       2048    923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     923648   1128447    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1128448   1161215     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1161216 408525630 407364415 194.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  408526848 409599999   1073152   524M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  409602048 976771071 567169024 270.5G Microsoft basic data
```

```
/dev/sdb1       2048   1085439   1083392   529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb2    1085440   1290239    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sdb3    1290240   1323007     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb4    1323008 266242047 264919040 126.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb5  266242048 266436607    194560    95M EFI System
/dev/sdb6  573442048 976771071 403329024 192.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb7  266436608 297687039  31250432  14.9G Linux swap
/dev/sdb8  297687040 573442047 275755008 131.5G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: Which disk is configured to boot first in your UEFI? What happens if you set it to the SSD and then change to the HDD? However before trying this remove the extra EFI partition you created for Ubuntu. Only one will work per disk. I had a similar scenario once. All I needed to do was copy the Ubuntu entries from the EFI partition on the HDD to the SSD and set the UEFI to boot the SSD first

Comment: When I set UEFI configuration to SSD and if I remove HDD from the order, it says no bootable. Later I just reinstalled both my Windows and Ubuntu, to solve it. 

Thank you for your comment.